# C# как получить доступ к компонентам формы в другом класе

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

у меня есть некая форма(WinForm)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    FileController fileController = new FileController();

    private void OpenFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fileController.OpenFolderInEditor();
    }

    private void ListBoxF_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

И есть класс в котором мне надо провести манипуляцию над списком который находится в ней(`ListBoxF`)

Я решил наследоваться от мой формы, и создать в классе экземпляр класса этой же формы(`Form1`)

```
class FileController : Form1
{
    Form1 form = new Form1();

    List<string> ListOfFiles;

    List<string> NameFile;
}
```

собственно, как мне редактировать список из другого класса?

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение, может кому поможет

проблема заключается в доступности компонентов формы, дизайнер форм автоматически выставляет им модификатор `private`

чтобы уйти от этой проблемы можно просто обернуть компонент, например `ListBox` в публичный метод
Пример:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public ListBox getListBox()
    {
        return listBox1;
    }

}
```